# Select-Object not selecting object from csv-file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import some csv files to further work with them and export them in the end. They all have two header lines from which i'll only need the second one. I also need to delete most columns except a few. Unfortunately it seems you'll need to decide if you want to skip rows with `get-content` *or* exclude columns with `import-csv`. Neither of those can't do both, so i got a workaround:

```
$out="bla\bla\out.csv"

$in="bla\bla\in.csv" 

$header= (get-content $in -TotalCount 2 )[-1]

$out = Import-csv $in -Header $header -Delimiter ";"|select column1 | Export-Csv -Path $out -NoTypeInformation
```

this returns an empty csv with the header name column1. What am i doing wrong?

Edit:

The input csv looks like:

```
filename;filename;...
column1;column2;...
1;a;...
2;b;...
...
```

I guess that `-Header` can't read arrays without single quotation marks, so i'm trying to find a solution to that atm.

Comment: How could we know without seeing the input file?  We can't help you unless we can see what the file looks like.  Show the top three or four rows of your `$in` csv.

Comment: Why did you define "$out = Import-csv...." ?

Comment: Added the input. I added $out to check what the desired output is without exporting a file each time.

Comment: Instead of splitting i tried the following: ```$headertemp= (get-content $in -TotalCount 2 )[-1].replace(";","','")
$header="'" + $headertemp + "'"```
The $header should be in the right format now, but i still get an empty output.

Comment: Seems like, `Get-Content $in | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object column1` should do what you're looking for

Comment: I tried a bazillion combinations of the commands in this line but yours works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the header you want to filter on, the following should do the trick and only requires reading the file once:

```
$out = "out.csv"
$in = "in.csv"

Get-Content $in | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object column1 |
        Export-Csv $out -NoTypeInformation
```

If however, you don't know the name of the header you need to filter on (`column1` on example above) but you know it's the first column, it would require an extra step:

```
$csv = Get-Content $in | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
$csv | Select-Object $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0] | Export-Csv $out -NoTypeInformation
```

We can get the first object of object array (`$csv[0]`) and get it's properties by accessing it's [`PSObject.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject) then select the *1st property* (`.Name[0]` - *column1* in this case).